# SQL Server: Limit filling NULL values up to row with specific text

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I have a CTE on which i am filling null values with the previous value before row 100 available by using the following script

```
SELECT [YearMonth],grp,
CASE WHEN grp>grp 
     THEN (FIRST_VALUE([Value 1]) over (partition by grp order by [YearMonth]))
```

The problem is that i want the rows after the "Latest" to be null but i dont want these rows to be deleted cause there are values in other columns which i need to show. I would appreciate of any help.

**EDIT**

Current Table

| YearMonth | Value 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01 | 0.9575 |
| 2021-02 | NULL |
| 2021-03 | NULL |
| 2021-04 | NULL |
| 2021-05 | NULL |
| 2021-06 | 0.9875 |

Expected table

| YearMonth | Value 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01 | 0.9575 |
| 2021-02 | 0.9575 |
| 2021-03 | 0.9575 |
| 2021-04 | 0.9575 |
| 2021-05 | 0.9575 |
| 2021-06 | 0.9875 |

Comment: `WHEN grp>grp` , really ?

Comment: You described the attempted solution, not the problem. What are you actually trying to do? Some windowing functions accept defaults. Finding the previous/next value is the job of `LAG` or `LEAD` anyway. Post a sample of data and the expected result and explain the logic. The solution may be far easier than what you expect. It won't include `grp>grp`

Comment: That's even less information than the question. If you want to use the previous value use `LAG(1)`, eg `LAG([Value 1]) OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY SomeField)`. Edit *the question* and include sample data, the desired output and if possible the logic.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have edited the question with the current table and the expected table. I wanted to fill NULL values with the previous available value.

Comment: at first add structure of table with complete select script to help you.